# Prevent style changing of the html select on size changing

Tags: javascript, html, css

How could I prevent style changing of the html `select` on `size` attribute changing?

```
<svg>

<foreignObject>
<select name="select1" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>5){this.size=5;}"  onchange='this.size=1;' onblur="this.size=0;">
             <option value="1">This is select number 1</option>
             <option value="2">This is select number 2</option>
             <option value="3">This is select number 3</option>
             <option value="4">This is select number 4</option>
             <option value="5">This is select number 5</option>
             <option value="6">This is select number 6</option>
             <option value="7">This is select number 7</option>
             <option value="8">This is select number 8</option>
             <option value="9">This is select number 9</option>
             <option value="10">This is select number 10</option>
             <option value="11">This is select number 11</option>
             <option value="12">This is select number 12</option>
           </select>
        </foreignObject>   
           </svg>
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/5sfkrju7/6/) is a fiddle, because for some reasons I can not run the html in the SO fiddle.

What I tried to do is to catch all style changes using the Chrome dev tools, but there are too many of them (changes).

I need to change the size so that to be able put a constraint onto the number of the options visible at once in the `select`.

In order to avoid a possible `x-y` problem: I need this to make a scrollable dropdown in `svg` using the `foreignObject` and html `select`.

I would like to be able to select only one option at a time.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8530173/html-select-limit-number-of-options-visible) question, specifically to the answer:

> The behavior depends on the browser and cannot he controlled by the author. You can use the size=10 attribute in the element, but it also changes the menu to a listbox so that 10 options will be visible even when the menu is not focused on. To achieve the behavior you describe, you would need to build your own controls using JavaScript and CSS.

I may tell that my question is about preserving the `menu` and not changing the style to the `listbox` style.

Comment: I think you are looking for the multiple attribute e.g. <select multiple ...>...</select>

Comment: @WNP, I updated the question a little bit.

Comment: The styling shouldn't change. E.g., if you set the background-color to yellow, it should stay yellow after you resize. There might be a problem with your CSS or with maybe try `max-height` instead.

Comment: @VictorStoddard, I provided the fiddle, please take a look at it. The style is definitely changing.

Comment: The style isn't changing on Chrome Version 67.0.3396.79 (Official Build) (64-bit). The width sometimes changes slightly when the digits change, but that's all.

Comment: @VictorStoddard, if you get rid from the `size` attribute (or set it to zero) you will get a different style for opened drop-down.

Comment: @Yaroslav Sorry about the full-screen captures. The styles look the same to me: https://s15.postimg.cc/r8rk4mqor/2018-06-12_3.png https://s15.postimg.cc/wwxuvlncb/2018-06-12_4.png

Comment: Have you found a solution for this @manymanymore?

Comment: @BAndrei, no I did not