# Dropdown Menu open height

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, menu, height

I have a simple dropdown menu:

```
<form class="feedmenu" align="center">
<select onchange="showRSS1(this.value)">
<option value="">Select an RSS-feed:</option>
<option value="ATO-HK">Asia Times</option>
<option value="HKH-HK">Hong Kong Herald</option>
<option value="Gov-HK">News.gov.hk</option>
<option value="RTHK-HK">Radio Television Hong Kong</option>
<option value="SCMP-HK">South China Morning Post</option>
<option value="STD-HK">The Standard</option>
</select>
</form>
```

How can I specify how large the dropdown box should be once you open it - the `size="x"` attribute does not do this, neither does the `height="x"` attribute.

Comment: Size should work, except in old versions of IE.

Comment: sorry, i'll explain more clearly: size makes the box permanently open. i want the box to be a normal dropdown box, but to dropdown longer, so there are more options on the screen when you click the button and it opens.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Height of an HTML select box (dropdown)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/570642/height-of-an-html-select-box-dropdown)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it doesn't look like you can change the height or number of items displayed in the dropdown without turning it into a listbox, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5538470/1405830).

If you really want to have control over it, then I would suggest making your own "dropdown" by creating an invisible list or table that becomes visible when you click the "dropdown". Sort of like multi-level menus, but styled to look similar to a dropdown.

**Edit:** Sorry, I hadn't read your comment before writing this. If you only want more options to be shown, then you can create empty ones for your dropdown. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/9ESWe/)